# url amigável em dois sub diretórios

Tags: php, htaccess, url

Estou tentando fazer funcionar a url amigável com o .htaccess
nele consta:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?g=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]+)\/([0-9]+)$ index.php?p=$1&c=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]+)\/([a-z_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1&s=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]+)\/([a-z_-]+)\/([0-9]+)$ index.php?p=$1&s=$2&c=$3
```

E eu tenho a seguinte estrutura:
www.site.com.br/coletor/admin/index.php?p=cadastrar

Quando eu executo fica assim:
www.site.com.br/coletor/admin/cadastrar/?p=cadastrar
e a tela fica toda branca.

Comment: Qual a sua estrutura de diretórios, onde está colocando os `htaccess`? Cada pasta deve ter o seu `htaccess`...

Comment: Correto! Fiz isso, dentro do diretório admin tem este .htaccess aí acima.

Comment: O que acontece quando acessa a url `www.site.com.br/coletor/admin/cadastrar`?

Comment: www.site.com.br/coletor/admin/cadastrar/?p=cadastrar

Comment: Redireciona pra essa?

Comment: Sim, redirecionou para essa

Comment: Veja teu PHP, porque `RewriteRule` não redireciona, apenas reescreve a URL para o PHP.

Comment: no link eu estou colocando assim:  <a href="/coletor/admin/cadastrar">link</a>

Comment: Adicione a seguinte regra: `RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]+)\/([a-z_-]+)\/([a-z_-]+)\/$ index.php?p=$1&s=$2&c=$3`